# Add custom add to cart button to product details page below add to cart section

Tags: magento2, addtocart

**i need help to add to custom add to cart button on products page below the products detail section..**
i tried this code in custom_addtocart.phtml page

## i am here

getCurrentCategory()): ?>
    
        getName(); ?>
    

 where i write i am here..i add add to cart button here